# Returning the result from a linq query but with one value modified

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class like this

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Category Category {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to query a List with Linq

```
var result = from p in products
             select p;
```

What I want to achive is that the result will set a default Category if it is empty.

What I can do is this

```
var result = from p in products
             select new Product()
             {
                 Id = p.Id,
                 Name = p.Name,
                 Category = p.Category ?? new Category() 
             }
```

but that requires me to set every field again.
But that is not what I want because my real world entity has about 50 properties not 3 and I also have to renember to edit the code If I add another property in the future.
What I am thinking is something more like this:

```
var result = from p in products
             select p { Category = p.Category ?? new Category() };
```

but that does not compile.

like I would do while constructing a product:

```
var product = new Product() { Category = new Category() };
```

I know I could just do this:

```
foreach (var p in result)
{
    if(p.Category == null)
        p.Category = new Category();
}
```

but I am passing the result to the caller an I don't want to itterate through my products at this moment.

Comment: Why aren't the properties initialized in the first place? If a product should have at least a category initialized with the default constructor, initialize the backing field accordingly.

Comment: If you're working with an ORM as datasource this may cause new Categories to be inadvertently inserted into the database.

Comment: That won't happen. Currently I am using the `select new Product...`  approach and reassign every property. With the disadvantage that I have to modify the code everytime I add another property to my class. This is dangerous. I will never store the result, and even if I would try, my model has a `[MinLength(5)]` dataannotation on category.name, so it would fail anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend doing this in Linq. You're mixing business logic ( null values should be default initialized) with DataAcess code (get me products).

Can you not change your product class itself. Modify the "Category" property to something like.

```
private Category _category

public Category Category 
{
    get 
    {
        if (_category == null)
            _category = new Category();

        return _category;
    }
    set
    {
        _category = value;
    }
}
```